# Jasper Login Page style custom changes

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I made jaser server Login Page style custom changes in overrides_custom.css file.
These changes are applying to the login page if I don't logout of jasper home page UI.
If I logout these changes are not applying.
Using Ubuntu linux.

Same changes works with the same version i installed on windows...

Please Help..
Thank You
Amannam

Answer (score 0):

The logout page will be same for all the users in the jasperserver.
In order to get the changes you need to login with the super user and do the changes then they will be effected.